# input type email throw warning in console. React

Tags: javascript, email, reactjs

When I'm trying to change state of `input[type="email"]` on `onChange` event using `this.setState({email: e.target.value})` I get this bunch of warnings in console (Chrome browser):

```
DOMPropertyOperations.js:143 The specified value "s" is not a valid email address.
DOMPropertyOperations.js:143 The specified value "so" is not a valid email address.
DOMPropertyOperations.js:143 The specified value "som" is not a valid email address.
DOMPropertyOperations.js:143 The specified value "some" is not a valid email address.
```

This strange behaviour occurs when you change `state`, if you pass data throw `props` all works great.

Any ideas?

P.S. I added `noValidate` to the form.

Comment: Can you try using the `this.isMounted()` like `if (this.isMounted()) {this.setState({email: e.target.value})}`

Comment: I will try, but don't understand how it's related, I'm sure that component is mounted

Comment: I tried what you offer and in latest react version `isMounted` method is deprecated instead it we should use componentWillMount, but its doesn't make sense in my case

Comment: It's currently a Chrome / React bug - you can read more about it in this issue from the official repository - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7487

Answer (score 0):

There is good documentation about what validation you can do on email inputs, read this and adapt your form:

[**Data form validation - Web developer guides | MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation#Example_that_doesn't_use_the_constraint_validation_API)

Validate through the correct REGEX also, and decide if you want live validation(keyup, keypress) or just when you lose focus on that input. Hope it helps you understand better and also help you in solving your problem.

Comment: this question is not about validation, its just a handling of controlled input in React which is throw to me strange warning